# Woes trying to debug a screensaver in MS Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, winapi, screensaver

I'm debugging a screensaver (written in C++ and liked to ScrnSavw.lib) and I need to run it through a local VS 2008 debugger. I managed to comment out screen rendering part so that I can see the screen but I can't seem to get the mouse out. It stays hidden. Any idea how to get the mouse back to working state so that I can use in VS2008 debugger window?

PS. I can't use remote debugger because the screensaver needs to run on this local system with VS2008 installed on it.

Comment: Use remote desktop to work with local debugger then.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But that would take too long to install debugging environment there. Is there a quicker fix to show the mouse?

Comment: Call `ShowCursor` right before the breakpoint. If it does't works, restore the default cursor using `SetCursor`.

Comment: Tried ::ShowCursor(TRUE); followed by ::SetCursor(::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)); right before the breakpoint and it didn't return the cursor. All I could do at that point is to use keyboard shortcuts in VS.

Comment: Can you use the keyboard for navigation ?

Comment: Yes, but it's somewhat inconvenient because VS doesn't have shortcuts for many commands and menu items.